# R webscraping setting keywords

Tags: r, web-scraping, keyword

I am web scraping in R from the WFP of the UN website in order to build up a dataset including the updates on food security (http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/). 
The packages are: rvest, stringr, tidyr, data.table, plyr, xml2, jsonlite.
Yet, I have imported into my dataset Country names, URL of the articles, Title of the articles and text of the articles.
Now, for the sake of parsing more easily, I would set up a new variable including some keyword I am interested in (e.g. "food security", "drought", etc.) and note the occurrencies of the aforementioned keywords. 
That variable would simplify enormously my research.
Any suggestion?

Here'a the basic code I am using.

```
## 01. Creating a function in order to scrape data from a website (in this case, FAO's)

WFP_get_news <- function(countries) {                                                      GET(
url = "http://www1.wfp.org/countries/common/allnews/en/",
query = list(countries=countries)
 ) -> res

 warn_for_status(res)

 if (status_code(res) > 399) return(NULL)

 out <- content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
 out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)
 out$countries <- countries

 tbl_df(out)
 }


## 02. Setting all the Country urls in order for them to be automatically scraped 

pb <- progress_estimated(length(countrycode_data$countries[]))   
map_df(countrycode_data$countries[], ~{
pb$tick()$print()
Sys.sleep(5) 
wfp_get_news(.x)
}) -> xdf



## 03. Setting keywords (of course, this process is arbitrary: one can    decide any keywor s/he prefers)
keywords <- c("drought", "food security")                                        


keyword_regex <- sprintf("(%s)", paste0(keywords, collapse="|"))


## 04. Setting the keywords search
bind_cols(                                                                                  
 xdf,
 stri_match_all_regex(tolower(xdf$bodytext), keyword_regex) %>% 
 map(~.x[,2]) %>% 
 map_df(~{ 
 res <- table(.x, useNA="always")
 nm <- names(res)
 nm <- ifelse(is.na(nm), "NONE", stri_replace_all_regex(nm, "[ -]", "_"))
 as.list(set_names(as.numeric(res), nm))
 })
 ) %>% 
 select(-NONE) -> xdf_with_keyword_counts
```

The result I get from point 04. is

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
 object "NONE" not found
Furthermore: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'data.frame'.
```

Any clue?

Comment: Please show us the code that you are trying to help you better

Comment: Shown the code upward

Comment: You can filter the data based on the keywords mentioned post scraping data `grep()` etc. should help. Any problem with that approach?

Comment: I am not sure that could work. I have to find the occurencies of the keyword I set too. At least, I don't know how to do that with `grep()`

Comment: wait. you're copying and pasting that for each country?

Comment: No, I created a fuction to attain that for each Country. Nevertheless, the outcome for the single country is that.

Answer (score 0):

First, a general rule to keep is if you cut/paste > 2-3x it's time for a function.

We'll need some help:

```
library(countrycode)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
```

Here's a function that you can call with an `iso3` code to get the data [frame] you want:

```
fao_get_news <- function(iso3) {

  GET(
    url = "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/common/allnews/en/",
    query = list(iso3=iso3)
  ) -> res

  warn_for_status(res)

  if (status_code(res) > 399) return(NULL)

  out <- content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
  out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)
  out$iso3 <- iso3

  tbl_df(out)

}
```

Now, we iterate over all possile `iso3` codes using a helper data frame from the `countrycode` package.

NOTE: remove the [1:20] in the next 2 lines for production to get all  I don't need all the data, so I'm not burning time/bandwidth. If you care abt ethics at all, not getting banned nor hammering the server(s) of a non-profit organization then keep the `Sys.sleep(5)` in there. If you're selfish, then still keep it in there b/c your needs aren't > the FAO's.

```
pb <- progress_estimated(length(countrycode_data$iso3c[1:20]))
map_df(countrycode_data$iso3c[1:20], ~{
  pb$tick()$print()
  Sys.sleep(5) # no crawl delay specified in site robots.txt so this is the ethical default
  fao_get_news(.x)
}) -> xdf
```

That gives us a nice, tidy data frame with all the news (with an `iso3` field):

```
glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 736
## Variables: 10
## $ uid         <chr> "1069933", "1069560", "1045264", "1044139", "103833...
## $ table       <chr> "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "ne...
## $ title       <chr> "FAO Calls for Stronger Collaboration on Transbound...
## $ date        <chr> "1511823600", "1511737200", "1508191200", "15081048...
## $ bodytext    <chr> "28 November 2017- Chief Veterinary Officers and ex...
## $ date_format <chr> "28/11/2017", "27/11/2017", "17/10/2017", "16/10/20...
## $ image       <chr> "http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/rne/img/I...
## $ pid         <chr> "50840", "16275", "70992", "16275", "2330", "40990"...
## $ detail_pid  <chr> "/neareast/news/view/en/c/1069933/", "/asiapacific/...
## $ iso3        <chr> "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "A...
```

Put all your keywords (lower case) here:

```
keywords <- c("drought", "food security")
```

We'll build a regex out of them

```
keyword_regex <- sprintf("(%s)", paste0(keywords, collapse="|"))
```

Now, we add keyword columns to our existing data frame. The outline of that the `stri_match…`++ is doing is that for each news blob:

- lower case the news blob
- find all occurrences of each keyword (if any) in a news blob
- capture a count of the # of occurrences along with the keyword
- (lightly) ensure the keyword can be a valid column name
- make a new column for each found keyword
- blobs without any keywords will just have an `NA` for the found count value

We could have made the keyword results data frame `count()` and `spread()` but it is is *not* a fast operation. Using `table()` means a bit more typing but much faster results.

```
bind_cols(
  xdf,
  stri_match_all_regex(tolower(xdf$bodytext), keyword_regex) %>% 
    map(~.x[,2]) %>% 
    map_df(~{ 
      res <- table(.x, useNA="always")
      nm <- names(res)
      nm <- ifelse(is.na(nm), "NONE", stri_replace_all_regex(nm, "[ -]", "_"))
      as.list(set_names(as.numeric(res), nm))
    })
) %>% 
  select(-NONE) -> xdf_with_keyword_counts
```

Here's the result:

```
glimpse(xdf_with_keyword_counts)
## Observations: 736
## Variables: 12
## $ uid           <chr> "1069933", "1069560", "1045264", "1044139", "1038339", "...
## $ table         <chr> "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", ...
## $ title         <chr> "FAO Calls for Stronger Collaboration on Transboundary A...
## $ date          <chr> "1511823600", "1511737200", "1508191200", "1508104800", ...
## $ bodytext      <chr> "28 November 2017- Chief Veterinary Officers and experts...
## $ date_format   <chr> "28/11/2017", "27/11/2017", "17/10/2017", "16/10/2017", ...
## $ image         <chr> "http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/rne/img/IMG_64...
## $ pid           <chr> "50840", "16275", "70992", "16275", "2330", "40990", "40...
## $ detail_pid    <chr> "/neareast/news/view/en/c/1069933/", "/asiapacific/news/...
## $ iso3          <chr> "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "ALA", ...
## $ food_security <int> NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, N...
## $ drought       <int> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting and way more elegant than mine. I will use it for sure! Thanks a million!

Comment: When I run
`pb <- progress_estimated(length(countrycode_data$iso3))`
I get the following error message

`Error in .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) : 
  lazy-load database '/home/.../Rdata.rdb' is corrupt



Inoltre: Warning messages:
1: In .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1`

Comment: sounds like one or more pkgs did not install well. best advice is to close out of R completely. reinstall package(s) and then start up again.

Comment: Ok, done.
Now I have this message:


`Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
  object "NONE" not found
Furthermore: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'bodytext'. `

Comment: Not sure how to help with local system errors. This — http://rpubs.com/hrbrmstr/forso-47670819 — proves it works in a bare session and shows all the pkgs/versions it loads.